# Ember ActiveModelAdapter URL without underscore?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have this json response to GET-request => /checklists

```
{"check_lists": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example-list-1",
        "description": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Example-list-1",
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

To handle the underscored naming-convention of this server, i use the ActiveModelAdapter and ActiveModelSerializer.

The problem i got stucked on is the request-url.
My model is named App.CheckList = DS.Model.extend({... and thats the point where it starts to get complicated.
if i call

```
return this.store.find('checkList');
```

in my route, Ember start a GET request to /checkLists route instead of /check_lists =>

```
GET http://localhost:3000/checkLists 404 (Not Found)
Error while processing route: checklists
```

surprisingly for this error the

```
buildURL: function(type, id) {
    return this._super(type, id);
},
```

is not used so i have no chance to modify the url.

Does anyone know how to change the request to /check_lists ??

Comment: What happens when you call `return this.store.find('check_list')`?

Comment: surprisingly this.store.find('check_list') results in the same error as this.store.find('checkList')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of camelized case and underscored case is done in `ActiveModelAdapter.pathForType` function.  You can override it and make your changes there.  For instance, to change from camelized case to underscored case:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var decamelized = Ember.String.decamelize(type);
    var underscored = Ember.String.underscore(decamelized);

    //Alternatively, you can change urls to dasherized case using this line
    //var dasherized = Ember.String.dasherize(decamelized);

    return Ember.String.pluralize(underscored);
  }
});
```

The strange part is that the latest Ember Data already has this code in [ActiveModelAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js#L121).  You may want to check the version you are running and upgrade to that instead of the change I suggest above.